# How to search in multiple pages in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Could someone help me to resolve the jqgrid issue?
I implemented the jqgrid pagination function, now there are two pages for the grid data but I try to search the result from all pages(Cross the pages)? Thanks!
It seems the jqgrid just support to search result from current page, does anybody met this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data doesn't contain too many lines then you can set

```
loadonce: true
```

With this property all data gets loaded from datasource once and therefore search works for all pages.

Otherwise your AJAX service is responsible for delivering searched data.

Comment: Thanks Knut. It seems that I will search the data via Ajax call. Because load all data once will spend much time to response.